# Actualizar archivo excel con python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Tengo un libro Excel que esta conectado a la base de datos. Cuando le doy actualizar traes los últimos datos registrado. El código que tengo guarda el libro pero no lo esta actualizando

```
import win32com.client
excel  = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
libro = excel.Workbooks.Open('ruta_del_libro_excel')
libro.RefreshAll()
libro.Save()
excel.Quit()
```

me sale al final esta alerta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que puede estar pasando o que me falta para lograr actualizar ese libro

Comment: Comproba que ninguna consulta esté usando «Habilitar actualización en segundo plano» (.BackgroundQuery debe ser False).

Comment: Recomiendas deshabilitar esa opción?

Comment: La opción tiene su uso; a veces es útil, a veces no lo es. En tu caso, tengo la sensación que si esta opción está activada, el efecto del `.RefreshAll` no se verá en el momento de la siguiente instrucción, que pide a Excel de... acabar todo e irse. Por tanto el resultado es que las «conexiones» no son actualizadas... probablemente no es el efecto buscado. Hay otros casos dónde `.BackgroundQuery` puede ser útil: el ejemplo evidente es si la base de datos está en la nube, y quieres hacer alguna cosa en lugar de mirar estúpidamente a la pantalla mientras se actualiza.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios. La solución fue entrar al archivo de Excel y en la parte donde se hace la consulta desactivar donde dice habilitar actualización en segundo plano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comprueba que ninguna consulta tenga activado la opción `Habilitar actualización en segundo plano` (en código VBA, `.BackgroundQuery` debe ser `False`).

Si esta opción está activada, el efecto del `.RefreshAll` no se verá en el momento de la siguiente instrucción, que pide a Excel de... ¡acabar todo e irse ya! Por tanto el resultado es que las «conexiones» no son actualizadas (aunque Excel te advierte que va a pasar).